# PHP ReCaptcha if else

Tags: php, forms, validation

OK I am trying to implement ReCaptcha on a simple form that posts to a DB. This form has a few different validation for validating the address is valid against LiveAddress API and deduping etc.

So I am trying to add ReCaptcha in the elseif like below, both of my other validation work but once it gets to ReCaptcha whether i enter a the captcha correct or incorrect when i hit submit it just goes to a blank page. With no errors.

I do have the correct public and private keys on my form and an includes for the recaptchalib.php. I can post that code if you think that would be helpful.

I am assuming that i need this to be in if else elseif below because if i just have all of the captcha code on the form like the example that you download it ignores the captcha all together it just get posted to the DB successfully, even if you don't put anything in the captcha input.

```
if(empty($errorMessage))
{
    // Dedupe the entry into the form
    $dupesql = "SELECT * FROM fromData WHERE (address = '$primary_number' AND city = '$city_name' AND state = '$state_abbreviation' AND zip = '$zipcode_full')";
    $duperaw = $mysqli->query($dupesql);

    // Check to make sure that they entered a valid address according to Liveaddress API
    if(empty($primary_number)){
        $bad_address .= "$bad_add in $bad_city, $bad_state is not a valid address please try again\n";
    }
    // Check to make sure that they have not already registered deduping on address, city, state, zip
    elseif($duperaw->num_rows > 0) {
        $dupe .= "$full_name already exists on $bad_add in $bad_city, $bad_state \n";
    }

    elseif( isset( $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"] ) )
    {
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

        if(!$resp->is_valid) {
            echo "reCaptcha incorrect";
        } else {
            echo "reCaptcha OK";
        }
    }

    // If all "elseif" fail then we insert them into our database
    else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO fromData (name, email, address, city, state, zip, date, optin, proccessed) VALUES ('$full_name', '$email', '$primary_number', '$city_name', '$state_abbreviation', '$zipcode_full', '$date', '$optin', 'No')";
        $mysqli->query($sql);
        echo $mysqli->error;

        header("location: index.php?success=1");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Can anyone see anything that is glaringly wrong with my code above? I have been moving the capcha code all around and it still isn't working. I am assuming that this is the closet i have to making it work the way that i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it now, last block of code `else { ... }` only gets executed if there are no previous errors (which is good) and if user entered nothing for captha (which is bad).

This is because if user enters anythnig for captcha, `elseif( isset( $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"] ) )` will happen and the last `else { ... }` will not be executed.

The code you want to execute if the captcha is correct should be in the

```
else {
  echo "reCaptcha OK";        
}
```

branch, not in the last `else` which only gets executed if variable which holds users response to captcha (I assumed you keep that in `$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]`)  is empty. So:

```
elseif( isset( $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"] ) ) { 
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],     $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]); 
  if(!$resp->is_valid) { 
    echo "reCaptcha incorrect"; 
  }
  else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO fromData (name, email, address, city, state, zip, date, optin, proccessed) VALUES ('$full_name', '$email', '$primary_number', '$city_name', '$state_abbreviation', '$zipcode_full', '$date', '$optin', 'No')";
    $mysqli->query($sql);
    echo $mysqli->error;
    header("location: index.php?success=1");
    exit();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @daew! I actually had tried that before i posted here. Having the post code in the else of the captcha. I have just tried again with your code snippet and i am getting the same thing when i click submit with or without the captcha it just goes to a blank page.

Comment: Can you post your HTML? If you always get a blank page no matter what, is it possible that your link in form( `action="..."`) is incorrect? Test by going to that link directly...
A classic way of doing this would be to have `onsubmit="..."` function, which checks everything and returns `1` if form is valid (including captcha).

Comment: Yeah i think i figured out my issue. I had part of the captcha code on a form.php include and the other part for the processing on index.php

As soon as i moved the form back to index.php it works as expected. So i am going to call this issue resolved and work on the other part where it display the form or an error message based on the number of submissions. I think that will be a lot easier to figure out then breakign the captcha code into 2 different files. I appreciate your help on this Cheers!